# Extract a full substring from a partial substring (needle)

Tags: php

As you can see below, I'm attempting to extract the complete substring of an exploded array by using just a few characters to match the substring.

```
$keyword = array('Four Wheel', 'Power', 'Trailer');
            function customSearch($keyword, $featurelistarray){
                $key = ''; //possibly reset output
                foreach($featurelistarray as $key => $arrayItem){
                    if( stristr( $arrayItem, $keyword ) ){
                $termname = $key;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The array ($featurelistarray) comprises vehicle options, four wheel drive, four wheel disc brakes, power windows, power door locks, floor mats, trailer tow package, and many many more.

The point is to list all the options for a given category, and using the $keyword array to define the category.

I would also like to alphabetize the results.  Thank you for the help!

To further explain, the $featurelistarray is exploded from a CSV field. The CSV field has a long length of options listed.

```
$featurelist=$csvdata['Options'];
        $featurelistarray=explode(',',$featurelist);
        $termname = $featurelistarray[0];
```

As you can see, $termname is assigned the first position of the exploded array.  This was the original code for these features, but I need more control for $termname.

Comment: I should point out, I've exploded a CSV field (earlier in the code) and yes the results are populating a MySQL database.  The database functionality is working fine.

Comment: Show us how do you call customSearch function. There is a $keyword array in your code. I hope you don't pass it to the customSearch function because stristr can't accept an array as a needle. Also I am not clear in what format would you like your output.

Comment: The output is populated into a Wordpress database.  The function call and $keyword array is where I'm having troubles.  Given my situation, how would you make it happen?  I don't have to use any of the code above, that's just what I've written so far, with no results.  While the syntax is correct, the result is null.

Comment: I understand, but can you show example of $featurelist array, like you did for $keyword array and desired structure of expected result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are trying to make database operations without database. I'd suggest to transform input into some kind of database.